# Once Examined, It's Satisfying

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

Can you solve the following puzzle?

> Wings The Cimarron Cavalcade Gone An Tom

> Hyd Hyd Lit Car Sil Cob Neo

> From Unthrifty Is But Let Let Against When Or Where 'Tis

**In sum, the answer is an eight-letter word.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:

> **Thirteen**

Because:

> Wings The Cimarron Cavalcade Gone An Tom

> These are the first words of Best Picture Oscar winners:
>  *Wings* - 1928 (1st)
>  *The Broadway Melody* - 1929 (2nd)
>  *Cimarron* - 1931 (4th)
>  *Cavalcade* - 1933 (6th)
>  *Gone with the Wind* - 1939 (12th)
>  *An American in Paris* - 1951 (24th)
>  *Tom Jones* - 1963 (36th)
>
>  And that sequence of ordinal positions is [OEIS A002182 - Highly composite numbers](https://oeis.org/A002182)
>  The next value in that sequence is 48, and the 48th Best Picture Oscar went to ***One** Flew Over The Cuckoo's Nest* in 1975

> Hyd Hyd Lit Car Sil Cob Neo

> These are abbreviated element names. There are a couple of choices for Sil and Neo, but the correct list is:
>  Hydrogen 1
>  Hydrogen 1
>  Lithium 3
>  Carbon 6
>  Silicon 14
>  Cobalt 27
>  Neodymium 60
>  And this sequence is apparently [OEIS A006951 - Number of conjugacy classes in GL(n,2)](https://oeis.org/A006951) (No I have no idea what that means either.)
>  Nevertheless, the next number in that sequence is 117, and element 117 is **Ten**nessine.

> From Unthrifty Is But Let Let Against When Or Where 'Tis

> These are the first words of Shakespeare sonnets.
>  Specifically the 1st, 4th, 9th, ... (square numbers), 121st
>  For completeness these are [OEIS A000290 - The squares](https://oeis.org/A000290), but I don't need that to work out the next value.
>  The next square is 144, and the 144th Sonnet starts with "**Two**"

Putting it all together:

> Continuing the pattern of first words (or first three letters) we get:
>  **One**
>  **Ten**
>  **Two**
>
>  And adding those up gives us **thirteen** which is eight letters as required.

Comment: Nice! Added a little bit to the question as a hint

Comment: Is the answer thirteen? They said "in sum"

Comment: @IsaacRoanSison I agree, question was updated with that hint after I posted

Comment: Also, the title is a hint to OEIS (Once Examined, It's Satisfying)

Comment: Ahh, I thought the title must contain a clue, just couldn't see what it was!